# Moment outputting time from now

Tags: javascript, validation, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I am using moment and moment-timezone to try and output how far away a future time is fromNow (in any timezone).

For example, if the input time was 1 day and *h* hours away from now, the output would be something like:

```
Tomorrow at hh:hh AM
```

Here is how I create my moment-timezone, with some example data:

```
  determineAirTime(dateTime) {
    console.log(dateTime); // May 12th 2014 8PM

    dateTime = 
 momentTimezone.tz(dateTime, "MMM Do YYYY hA", momentTimezone.tz.guess());

    console.log(dateTime) // 2014-05-12T20:00:00-04:00
  }
```

**My problem** is converting the above time (2014-05-12T20:00:00-04:00), to a more readable format. Such as `tomorrow at 8:00pm`, where it takes into account the timezone.

I've tried `fromNow()` and `calendar()` in moment, but they only output how many days it will be.

How can I convert my moment-timezone string to an exact date/day/seconds from the currentTime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be careful will "friendly" formats, many users find them annoying. Anyhow, you can use the [*calendar*](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/calendar/) method:

```js
// Create a date for 13:15:23 tomorrow
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
d.setHours(13,15,23);
// Show friendly format
console.log(moment(d).calendar());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I toned it down a bit,  if by friendly formats you meant all the italtics/etc. Your solution was something I've tried, but it only outputs the amount of days. E.g. console.log( moment(dateTime).calendar()); Outputs "x days"

Comment: Actually, I tried it with some different values, and it seems to work. I'll do a little more testing